# Why 2 functions don't want to work in same time

Tags: autohotkey

My 2 functions don't want to work in same time! How to run 2 or more functions in same time.
After I press Start button for one second MainF() function works and after Damage() function starts run MainF() stops.

How to solve it??

PS. I dont want to have 2 scripts.

Thanks for help.

Code below:

```
ButtonStart:

SetTimer, PGD, 1000

MainF()

PGD:

Damage()

return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You realize that since there is no return after MainF(), that Damage() will run as soon as MainF() has finished.... AND after 1 second again and again. However since you did not make your script Persistent, It will close after the first return and never be triggered by the timer....

```
#SingleInstance Force
#installKeybdHook
#Persistent
SetTimer, PGD, 2000
MainF()
PGD:
Damage()
Return

MainF()
{
        SoundBeep, 500, 100
}

Damage()
{
        SoundBeep, 2000, 100
}
Return
```